# How to reparent using tree.hh

Tags: c++, n-ary-tree

Here I have a window with a list of groups of rows. In the image above, Path 2 to 6 are children of Group1.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zb4FB.png

The container used for this tree is [tree.hh](http://tree.phi-sci.com/documentation.html). What function would I use to make Group1 (and its children) be child of Path 10. I don't want to delete rows and put them back again, just re-parent. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you should look at [`::move_after()`](http://tree.phi-sci.com/doxygen/html/classtree.html#e7f72ba46cd061f71720c731b4a9bf63)